# Prove $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$ is an ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $S$ be a right ideal of ring $R$.  Let $\operatorname{ann}_r(S) = \{r \in R:ar=0 \mbox{ for all } a \in S\}$.  Prove $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$ is an ideal of $R$.

I have practically no experience in making ring theory proofs.  I can prove that $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$ is a group under the addition of R.  I want to show that for all $x \in \operatorname{ann}_r(S)$ and for all $r \in R$ that $xr, rx \in \operatorname{ann}_r(S)$.  Let $x$ be arbitrary in $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$ and $r$ be arbitrary in $R$.  Then $ax = 0$.  So $axr=0r=0=a(xr)$. So $xr$ is in $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$.  How can I show that $rx$ is in $\operatorname{ann}_r(S)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $rx \in \def\ann{\mathop{\rm ann}}\ann_R(S)$ for $x \in \ann_R(S)$, $r \in R$, let $a \in S$. As $S$ is a right ideal of $R$, we have $ar \in S$. Hence 
$$ a(rx) = (ar)x = 0 $$
as $ar \in S$, $x \in \ann_R(S)$.